# mgcb editor (monogame) wont launch or download

Tags: .net, monogame

i tried installing mgcb via nuget using vs. vs says:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Package 'dotnet-mgcb-editor 3.8.0.1641' has a package type 'DotnetTool' that is not supported by project 'Game2'.

and dotnet tool says I need `dotnetcore` app 3.1. and won't download the file.

so then I download the nupkg file and unzip it and when i tried to start the .exe it wouldn't start

and so far I have not found a way to download/start the editor.

how do i fix this and download mgcb?

Answer (score 1):

From Monogame3.8, you need to have dotnet-sdk installed (regardless of whether you are using Windows/Mac/Ubuntu). You haven't specified your OS, so go to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download and install it in your system. (If you are using Windows, you might want to install dotnet-sdk from Visual Studio).

With dotnet installed and added in the PATH, open a terminal and enter this command to install mgcb-editor

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-mgcb-editor
```

And you're good to go.

Edit: Do not use dotnet 5 preview release. Right now the RC is dotnet SDK 3.1 and that's the one to use

Comment: Nope wont work.... error NU1202: Package dotnet-mgcb-editor 3.8.0.1641 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1) / any. Package dotnet-mgcb-editor 3.8.0.1641 supports: netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1) / any
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'dotnet-mgcb-editor' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET Core tool.

Comment: @TheSlam Yes. I didn't specify it in the answer, but you shouldn't have used the preview release. dotnet SDK 3.1 was the one you needed. If it's solved now, kindly upvote